# How to pass Date as parameter in jasper report using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass start & end date as parameter to jasper report but it is not working properly. I am getting a blank PDF. When I hardcode start & end date in the SQL query itself, I am getting right output in PDF.

Using Mysql, eclipse luna, jre1.7, jaspersoft plugin & all required jars are in Lib folder.

My Servlet code -

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "password");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream =response.getOutputStream();
    InputStream reportStream =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("Blank_A4_Table_Based.jasper");
    SimpleDateFormat eformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date sDate = eformat.parse("2015-08-25");
    String sdate=eformat.format(sDate );
    System.out.println(sdate);
    Date eDate = eformat.parse("2015-08-26");
    String edate=eformat.format(eDate );
    System.out.println(edate);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("sdate",sDate);
    parameters.put("edate",eDate);
    JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, parameters, connection);
    connection.close();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    servletOutputStream.flush();
    servletOutputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // display stack trace in the browser
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
}
```

Jasper report JRXML -

```xml
<parameter name="sdate" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="edate" class="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>                               
<queryString>                                               
    <![CDATA[SELECT id, session_reason FROM session_details WHERE created BETWEEN $P{sdate} AND $P{edate})]]>
</queryString>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have properly designed your report.
2. It is working fine with iReport 5.6.0. It may be a bug in Jaspersoft Studio V6.0

*I will say make that report in iReport & check whether the issue still persists.*

**EDIT - *Things to remember***

> public Timestamp(int year,
>                               int month,
>                               int date,
>                               int hour,
>                               int minute,
>                               int second,
>                               int nano)

***Deprecated. instead use the constructor Timestamp(long millis)***

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** OP has changed question in orign was passing a String to jasper now its a Date..

You are using $P in query so jasper report tries do generate prepared statment inserting your variables.

**Solution 1**: Change the parameter's to the correct object (`java.sql.Timestamp`)

```
<parameter name="sdate" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

and pass a `java.sql.Timestamp` object

```
 parameters.put("sdate",new java.sql.Timestamp(sDate.getTime());
```

**Solution 2**: Use query substitution and not prepared statmentet:

change in your jrxml:

```
<queryString>                                               
<![CDATA[SELECT id, session_reason FROM session_details WHERE created BETWEEN '$P!{sdate}' AND '$!P{edate}']]>
</queryString>
```

pass as parameter the `String` value's

```
parameters.put("sdate",sdate); //The string
```

and setup the jrxml parameter's as `String`

```
 <parameter name="sdate" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

The key of this code is $P!{} see the **!**, basically is does string substitution so I also added the date qualifier ' ' since you are using mysql.

Some other general notes (even if you say it works without parameters):

1. Normally the driver needs to be registred...

   ```
   Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
   ```
2. There seems to be a ) to much in the query
3. response.setContentType("application/pdf"); before you push report to stream
4. Optional, use try,catch,finally {//close the connection.. }

Comment: I have already tried using java.util.Date, java.sql.Date but it is not working.

Comment: Solution 2 is also not working.. I am still getting a blank PDF.

Comment: How is your sql without parameters, testing in my eclipse now... 5 s

Comment: sql without parameters is working fine. Returning all values.

Comment: show me sql without values, I have tried with mysql and java.sql.Timestamp and it works, see edit of answer

Comment: Have also tried second solution and with mysql works well.

Comment: SELECT id, session_reason FROM session_details WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-08-25' AND '2015-08-26') is this your exact query that works when not using parameters??

Comment: So if you now pass the String value (the sdate) having parameter as java.lang.String the second solution will create the exact same query... be carefull because second solution expect strings..

Comment: Both Solutions are giving me a Blank PDF. Is problem somewhere else like in jars or some config?

Comment: output the parameters to the report..., its not config if with exact same query as above and solution 2 does not work passing the exact same paramters... do a text field with same expression as your query so you can see it!, check for typo do you have the '' in second solution..

Comment: For example in your code the sql its seems that in the end you have a ) to much..., what is your stacktrace telling you...

Comment: Futhermore I do not see you register the driver... but if you say that the exact same query works... I guess the connection works without registring.... when you say it works this I hope means from your application... not from iReport or similar...

Comment: Yes i am testing above code on ecilpse- java dynamic web application. I used jaspersoft plugin for jasper report. Output is a blank pdf.

Comment: If its not blank putting same query in jasper report without parameters (executing the report from web application, not plugin), This is not a confiugration problem (since the connection ecc, seems to be working).As I said put the query with parameters in a textfield in example the title band remeber to set whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" on jasper report and try... this way you see the query arriving (use solution 2 that is easiest to debug)

Comment: Futhermore since you use eclipse you can debug your application (both by stepping) but also print out the error (pretty sure you have an error), instead of Exception catch Throwable and output it to the console e.printStackTrace(); Also check my last 2 general notes.. in answer

Comment: No. I think this is a problem with Jaspersoft V6.0. I will shift to iReport & let you know! :)

Comment: Hey! It is working fine with iReport. All of your answers was based on iReport, right?

Comment: Not really, they where based jrxml (jasper report), iReport is just a visual tool to develop them...

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
 try {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path to jasper file");
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        // set your parameters
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        // For the "Save As" dialogue
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "yours PDF file name");
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException | JRException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This should have never happened");
    }
```

I suggest you pass dates as formatted string values and change your JR parameters to String.

Also i don't understand why do you create jdbc connection but do not use it.

Comment: Seriously dude! without jdbc connection from where i will fetch the data?  JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, parameters, connection); Please try to understand i am using connection!

Comment: I am just trying to tell you that it is good practice to fetch data from db, put them into a Map and after that send to Jasper. In this case JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(JasperPrint jasperPrint, OutputStream outputStream) can do the trick because does not require jdbc connection.

Comment: Fetch data from database and put them in the map.... hmmm thats the parameter map not the datasource.... I guess this trick is a bit tricky..., if you fill a JRDataSource ok... but the passing connection last time that I checked works in jasper report